# r - ggplot2 barplot of binary data

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I've a column of a dataset like : [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, ...] where 1 is male and 2 female.

What I want is to create a plot like the one in the pictures but I couldn't.

```
  ggplot( aes(x=age)) +
    geom_density(fill="#69b3a2", color="#e9ecef", alpha=0.8)
```

I don't know how to put instead of the range [-0.5, 0.5] for male, indicates male, and [0.5, 1.5] female.

[image: An example of what I want - a bar plot with counts for female and male]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The x-axis is a numeric value because you are passing a numeric vector. Converting it to a character vector is probably the easiest approach.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Original data
df <- data.frame(gender = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2))

# Convert to character
df <- df %>% mutate(Gender = case_when(gender == 1 ~ "Male",
                                 gender == 2 ~ "Female"))
# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = Gender)) +
  geom_bar() + 
  ggtitle("Gender")
```

[image]

Comment: it works, thanks. There is just a typo: instead of "aes(x = gender)" you should put "aes(x = Gender)".

Comment: Good call, fixed it.